# Untrusted deserialization strategy

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, mono

I have a pretty complex web of objects I'd like to serialize and deserialize in an untrusted environment (web browser, using Unity 3D).   Plain `BinaryFormatter` serialization is working fine, but deserialization crashes with "access to private field" errors.  It works perfectly when I am running locally.

I would rather not make my codebase suck by making all my private fields public.  What is the best way to get deserialization to work in an untrusted environment without doing this?  I am open to changing serialization methods, `BinaryFormatter` was just the easiest to get started with.

**UPDATE** I don't want to prevent serialization from accessing my private data, I want to *allow* serialization to access my private data without having to make it public, compromising the encapsulation of my code.

Thanks.

Comment: is this a asp.net application?

Comment: @Saurabh, no.  It's unity3d, a browser plugin that runs .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Serializers like `XmlSerializer` and `JavaScriptSerializer` work against the public members, so they *should* (crosses fingers) work acceptably in terms of trust. You could also try protobuf-net if you want binary - but I haven't aggressively tested this scenario (it works in things like Silverlight, though, which has a fairly picky trust model).

If you want to stick with `BinaryFormatter` but don't want it touching your fields directly you could implement `ISerializable`, but doing it all manually is... painful.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers really answered my question (see the update for clarification).  I ended up writing my own simple serialization format using `BinaryWriter`. In the end I realized what I did was equivalent to manually implementing the `ISerializable` interface for my classes.  I had to manually implement the graph serializatoin code.  While not hard, it's a bit subtle, and it has already been done for me.  For future perople with this question, if there are no better answers, I recommend manually implementing `ISerialzable`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to prevent the private field access by serialization, you may want to move over to Xml Serialization of perhaps even Json serialization.

You can prevent the private fields from serializing by placing NonSerializaed attributes on them, but you may run into problems when developers expect their fields to contain valid values and do not take into account the fact that those field values get lost when transferred to the Unity plugin.

Comment: (adding `[NonSerialized]`) That would of course mean that it didn't really serialize anything - unless I misunderstand you

Comment: No, you didn't misunderstand. Like I mentioned, values in NonSerialized fields get lost and that either requires some serious attention in scenarios where something like a low level command pattern is used, or in the more likely scenario, a switch to either Json or Xml Serialization.